# How to set the environmental variable for AndroidViewClient?

Tags: environment-variables, monkeyrunner, androidviewclient

I have monkeyrunner set up and am trying to set up AndroidViewClient as well. I followed the tutorial at https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki, doing a pip install, and added the env path to my bash profile using the code:

```
export ANDROID_VIEW_CLIENT_HOME=/Users/me/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/AndroidViewClient-master
```

I made sure to re-source my bash. However, when I run python check-import.py --debug from the /examples folder, I receive the error:

```
File "check-import.py", line 22
    print("WARNING: '%s' is not a directory and is pointed by ANDROID_VIEW_CLIENT_HOME environment variable" % avcd, file=sys.stderr)
                                                                                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm not very familiar with environmental variables so I could have easily made a mistake that I didn't catch.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed `androidviewclient` via `pip` like

```
pip install androidviewclient
```

and it didn't give you any errors, then `androidviewclient` should be installed and available to your scripts via `import` or command line via its commands (i.e. `dump`, `culebra`).

You don't need any environment variables.

Then when you run

```
./check-import.py --debug
```

you will see your python path printed and then

```
OK
```

It seems you have changed this line https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/blob/master/examples/check-import.py#L22

**AndroidViewClient/culebra** requires python 2.7.x, so if you have a different version on your system you can install https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv or other virtual environment.

Comment: I am running python 2.7.10 and didn't change the check-import file at all. I installed the AndroidViewClient in the Android/sdk/tools/bin folder, where monkeyrunner and my python files are located, is that correct? Also I added "export ANDROID_VIEW_CLIENT_HOME=/Users/me/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/AndroidViewClient-master" to my bash_profile, are you saying I should remove that?

Comment: If you install `androidviewclient` with `pip` you don't need anything else, no environment variables, no extra downloads, etc.